# javascript + semantic ui: vertical menu with dialog between items, how?

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

what I want, vertical menu:

```
menu item 1
menu item 2
```

user pressed `menu item 1` and on the same page,
appear input dialogue between two menu items:

```
menu item 1
  input field 1
  input field 2
  button
menu item 2
```

It is rather simple two create `vertical menu list` and
dialogue with such content, but how to combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you can try with an [*accordion menu*](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html), see the follow example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // init the accordion on the menu
  $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui vertical fluid accordion menu">
 <div class="item">
  <a class="title">
   <i class="dropdown icon"></i>Menu item 1
  </a>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="ui form transition hidden">
    <form class="ui form">
     <div class="field">
      <label>Input field 1</label>
      <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="Input field 1">
     </div>
     <div class="field">
      <label>Input field 2</label>
      <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Input field 2">
     </div>
     <button class="ui button" type="submit">Button</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <a class="title">
   <i></i>Menu item 2
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps,